# PHP title depends from a variable

Tags: php

Im trying to display a title that depends from a variable,
below is my code:

```
<?php 
$id = $_GET["id"];
$title1 = 'Title 1';
$title2 = 'Title 2';
$title3 = 'Title 3';
?>
```

Now how to print `title2` if `id='2'`,
something like `echo $title($id)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isn't it better to put your titles into an array ?

```
$id = (int) $_GET["id"];
$title = array(
  1 => 'Title 1',
  2 => 'Title 2',
  3 => 'Title 3'
);

echo $title[$id];
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed, (I'm new in PHP).
I've putted titles in array now, tested and working.

Comment: @hsz possibly because you didn't actually answer the OP's question; you changed the question to a different problem and solved that. For this OP, they were willing to change their structure, but future visitors may not be able/willing  to and do need an answer to the original problem.

Comment: @AlbiHoti Your welcome. If you find my answer helpful, mark it as an answer with tick under the answer's score. Do it also with answer for your recent questions please.

Comment: @MidnightLightning Sometime it's better to change the way you go to achieve the goal.

Comment: @hsz Agreed, however sometimes that's not possible. Sometimes the examples given by question-askers are oversimplifications to focus on one issue. If the series of title variables was actually defined by external extension scripts in a library that each defined their own title, reworking all of them to use an array would be a much larger undertaking than using a variable-variable to get the proper title.

Comment: @MidnightLightning Sure thing. I do not know about it, however I show my way to solve the problem and if it matches with OPs requirements, he just choose it, otherwise he doesn't. Simple. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The following should do the trick for you:

```
<?php 
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    switch($id)
    {
        case 1:
            $title = 'Title 1';
            break;
        case 2:
            $title = 'Title 2';
            break;
        case 3:
            $title = 'Title 3';
            break;
        default:
            $title = 'Something else';
            break;
    }

    echo $title;
?>
```

Comment: While this will be somewhat more robust in terms of what it can do (anything can be done inside a switch statement), for this particular question, the array solutions are much more elegant. I have +1'ed both array solutions.

Answer (score 4):

You can user an Array :

```
$title = array(
     1 => 'Title 1',
     2 => 'Title 2',
     3 => 'Title 3'
);
```

And for have your title with your get :

```
$title[$_GET['title']];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
$id = $_GET["id"];
$title_var = 'title'.$id; // Save the whole name of the variable as a string

$title1 = 'Title 1';
$title2 = 'Title 2';
$title3 = 'Title 3';

echo $$title_var; // Note the double dollar sign for a variable-variable
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use something like `echo ${"title{$id}"};`

Comment: +1 for simplest answer working **within** the OP's existing structure, rather than suggesting a structure rework.

Answer (score 1):

Using `$$` may be smart idea like:

```
<?php 
$id=1;
$id = "title".$id;
$title1 = 'Title 1';
$title2 = 'Title 2';
$title3 = 'Title 3';
echo $$id;
?>
```